DocTR issue showing while importing in vscode
for this 'from doctr.models import ocr_predictor'- showing error-"OSError: cannot load library 'gobject-2.0-0': error 0x7e.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'gobject-2.0-0'"
why is it and how to resolve this problem?
I am working on it for 1st time so i don't have that much of idea on it...
